# Weird glitches on Intel iGPU

Tags: multiple-monitors, integrated-graphics, intel-core-i5

I have a weird problem that I can't manage to describe in one word, so I'm having trouble searching for a solution.

My monitors sometimes go black for a tenth of a second. Other times, they show the image shifted a few centimeters to the left or to the right. This happens on both of my monitors, but not necessarily at the same time.

I would say it happens about once a minute, unless under heavy load, in which case it can happen every second or so. Interestingly, heavy CPU/memory usage can also cause this, not just heavy GPU usage. This only happens when they are both at 1920x1080, not when one of them, or both, are at a lower resolution. It also happens when they are in mirrored mode instead of extended desktop mode.

My GPU is obviously not at full clock speed most of the time: this happens at 350 MHz as well as at 1200 MHz. So it doesn't seem like a matter of too little performance. I'm not seeing any traditional artefacts, even when I use MSI Kombustor, only this kind of full-screen glitches. CPU stressing software isn't reporting any issues either.

I'm thinking maybe the connection between my CPU and my PCH isn't fast enough, but I can't find anyone with the same problem to confirm that. I'd rather not invest in a discrete GPU without being certain it will fix something.

Does anyone know how to search for this, or even better, does anyone have a solution? My full specs are below. Thanks in advance!

#### Specs:

- ASUS P8Z77-M
- Intel Core i5-3570K (with Intel HD 4000 Graphics)
- 2x4 GB AMD Performance Edition memory
- Corsair Force 3 Series Rev. B 120GB SSD
- Maxtor 200GB HD
- Lite-On DVD-RW
- Antec 350 Watt PSU
- 64-bit Windows 7 Professional
- 2x Iiyama ProLite E2208HDS display

**Edit 2012-06-12:**

I've tried connecting a very old video card I had laying around, and using both this GPU and the iGPU using Lucid Virtu MVP. There is serious performance degradation, as I assume the video card can't keep up with the iGPU, but the problems disappear. This even when I connect my monitors to the motherboard and not to the VGA port on the video card. So just connecting the video card is enough to solve the problem (but at the same time causes bad performance). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried updating your system drivers (motherboard chipset, graphics, etc.) and motherboard BIOS to the latest versions?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that, sorry. I have.

Comment: I forgot to update this question, but this was fixed with a driver update released later.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with a very similar setup the glitches dissapeared when i installed two new PC19200 RAM modules in slots #2 and #4.

if your memory modules are in slots #1 and #3 you can try to move them to slots #2 and #4. It seems that the memory bandwidth is greater in that slots.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had already moved them to slots 2 and 4 before, after hearing those are sometimes more stable. Moving them didn't noticeably change anything. Thanks though!